# Most Frequent Number with array

Tags: c++, arrays

Hello i wrote  program that is displaying most  frequent Number but when they are more than one frequent Number i want do display frequent Numbers
 For example:

7 7 7 0 2 2 2 0 9 9 9 
 i want to display  2 7 9

Thank you in advance

this is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;


int main()
{

    int arrSize;
    cin >> arrSize;

    int arr[arrSize] = {0};

    for(int k = 0; k < arrSize; ++k)
    {
        cin >> arr[k];
    }


    int most_Frequent_num = 0;
    int print_index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= arrSize; ++i)
    {
        int counter_Frequent_loop = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j <= arrSize; ++j)
        {
            if(arr[i] == arr[j])
            {
                counter_Frequent_loop++;
            }
            if(most_Frequent_num < counter_Frequent_loop)
            {
                most_Frequent_num = counter_Frequent_loop;
                print_index = arr[i];

            }

        }


    }
    cout << print_index << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i <= arrSize; ++i)` will cause an off by 1 error. You repeat this bug again. It should be `for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i)` the reason is `arr[arrSize]` is one past the end of the array.

Comment: thank you for the fast answer . when i put this input  7 7 7 0 2 2 2 0 9 9 9 it displays only  7 i want to display  2 7 9

Comment: An easy way to solve this is to use a `std::map<int,int>`

Comment: @drescherjm is there way to make it without map ? i mean to solve it with one more loop or something else ?

Comment: A solution is here: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-frequencies-of-array-elements/](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-frequencies-of-array-elements/)

Comment: @drescherjm thank you very much for the help and im sorry if the question was stupid.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fairly easy method to do this. Use an `std:: unordered_map<int, int>`, count the frequencies of array elements and also find out the maximum frequency in the map. Then simply traverse the map and you are done.

Is this what you're looking for?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    int *arr{ new int[11]{ 7, 7, 7, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 9, 9, 9 } };
    int max_frequency = INT_MIN;

    unordered_map<int, int> hash;

    for(auto x = 0; x < 11; ++x) {
    hash[arr[x]]++;
    max_frequency = max(max_frequency, hash[arr[x]]);
    }

    for(auto x: hash) {
    if(x.second == max_frequency)
        cout << x.first << " ";
    }
    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes i have one more question is it possible without use map .I mean to use something like for loop ? and thank you very much for the useful answer

Comment: Why do you want an inefficient solution?